# How to provide several examples of working function?

Tags: c++

Assume I have a function:

```
void isUniqueSymbols(string stream)
```

How to understand that I should provide several examples of how my function works?
I can write something like this:

```
Input: isUniqueSymbols("abcde");
Output: true;

Input: isUniqueSymbols("abcdee");
Output: false;
```

But not sure this is correct.

How would you provide examples of working function?

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question?

Comment: Are you asking us how to document your function? There is no objectively "correct" way. Do whatever you want. What you've written already is fine. This isn't a suitable question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's still not clear what exactly you are trying to do. Is it about [unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C.2B.2B)? Reminds me [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) where it often happens that function is defined by input-output pairs that should be always followed once it's implemented...

Comment: Your question can be interpreted in a lot of different ways...

Comment: @LihO Don't think it's TDD. I have such point: Provide several examples that call your function and demonstrate that it works. And only one thing that I have at my mind is that lines at my question. Maybe you guys know a little more about this.

Comment: So you were given an assignment that says "Provide several examples that call your function and demonstrate that it works" and you came here to ask how we understand this assignment?

Comment: @LihO Yes and provide my assumption.

Comment: I think you are supposed to write few code snippets that present the possible usage of this function. And by "demonstrate that it works" I understand that you are also supposed to turn these code snippets into working application that someone will run and see expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be the embed the documentation into code:

```
assert(isUniqueSymbols("abcde"));
assert(!isUniqueSymbols("abcdee"));
```

This is pretty close to unit testing/viewing unit tests as documentation, for whatever that may be worth.

Comment: +1 for reasonable answer that fits the OP's description although it's really hard to tell what was being asked here.